# makefile not generating executeble files

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I am fairly new at makefile. I am trying to create a makefile that compiles yu.c and link yu.c to get a executable file called yu.
Below is the code i have. I am using make -f mymakefile to run the file and each time i run it, only gcc -c yuFile.c is done.
Where am I wrong?

```
CC=gcc

yu.o: yuFile.c
    ${CC} -c yuFile.c
yu: yuFile.o
    ${CC} yu -o yuFile.o
run-c: yu
    ./yu
clean:
    rm -f "*.o" core
```

Comment: A bit confused about the first target. That would create a file yuFile.o, so it'll never be satisfied. Actually yuFile.o -> yuFile.o is a built in target, so you don't need even the first one. Remove the `yu.o:` target, then reverse the `yu:` and `run-c:` targets. The first target will be `run-c:` which will be the default target. If you update `yuFile.c`, the Makefile will rebuild `yuFile.o` and then link `yu` and then run `run-c:`.

Comment: A general suggestion to debug `Makefile`-s is to use `remake` (notably with its `-x` flag).

Answer (score 2):

`make` with no target specified makes the first target in the file, so in your case it is equivalent to `make yu.o`.

Typically, you make the first target `all` so that everything is built:

```
all: yu
.PHONY: all
```

(Note that the `.PHONY` prevents `make` from doing nothing if there's a file named `all` already).

Worth pointing out: you've got your arguments reversed in the `yu` target. It should be

```
yu: yuFile.o
    ${CC} yuFile.o -o yu
```

or more generically

```
yu: yuFile.o
    ${CC} $^ -o $@
```

(`$^` means all prereqs, and `$@` means the target, as documented in [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)).

Comment: I made these changes to my code. Now, a executable files is generated. But I was hoping after the linking stage, the generated executable file be executed. it seems that run-c: yu  ./yu  is still not working.  the clean line is not working either.

Comment: @user1559897: If you're just typing `make` then it will just make the first target, which in this case is `all`.  If you want to type `make` and have the program run, then change the all line to be `all: run-c`.

Answer (score 0):

The first target is the one picked when no argument is specified.
The standard is to have an 'all' target first:

all: yu

Also, your 'yu' target is incorrect.

```
yo: yufile.o
   $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

should work

Comment: Right, sorry. $@ is the target, $^ is the dependencies for said target